# HTTP parameter with the name 'url' causes strange result for my Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web-applications

I asked this before but I'm stuck with another issue. Say, if I load my page like so:

```
http://localhost:57845/api.ashx?v=123&usr=&url=
```

and then try to do:

```
string strUser = context.Request["usr"];
string strURL = context.Request["url"];
```

both `strUser` and `strURL` will be set to "", which I would expect.

But if call it like this:

```
http://localhost:57845/api.ashx?v=123
```

`strUser` will be `null`, which I would also expect, but `strURL` will be set to "/api.ashx".

Why is that???

Comment: try using Request.QueryString["usr"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is coming from the [`ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) part of the request. You'd likewise get a value if you asked for `remote_addr` or any of the other [server variables supported by IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) (assuming you're coming through IIS).

If you *only* want to get parameters from the query string, use the [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) property:

```
string strUrl = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
```

(I'd also *strongly* recommend that you get rid of the type-prefixes on your variable names, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks. You see the reason I used straight `context.Request` is because I can get input from both GET and POST...

Comment: @user843732: Do you not know where a specific parameter will come from? You can use `context.Request.QueryString` and `context.Request.Form` to get the query string and form variables respectively... so it's not like you *can't* handle POST requests. You could always write your own method to fetch from just those two sources, ignoring server variables and cookies. But anyway, that's why you're getting a value for `url` :)

Comment: Thanks. It's probably easier to use another parameter :(

Comment: Just from curiosity, what is bad about using type-prefixes on my variable names?

Comment: @user843732: You've already got the type of the variable there in your declaration. If your method is reasonably short, you should be able to see it easily anyway. The prefix just adds fluff. Additionally, it's explicitly against conventions when it comes to things like parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. I honestly haven't heard anything about the conventions you refer to (you're free to link to them.) I base it on my own experience. For a larger chunk of code it always helps (for me) to see the type of the variable by its name.

Comment: @user843732: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045.aspx - "Do not use Hungarian notation.
Hungarian notation is the practice of including a prefix in identifiers to encode some metadata about the parameter, such as the data type of the identifier."

Comment: Thanks. I guess I do use Hungarian notation, even though I am not a Hungarian :) Still, I don't understand the reason not to? That article plainly states "Microsoft thinks that you should..." but it doesn't say why... In either case, I attribute such discussion to arguing over someone's favorite color or a taste. What is fluff to you might be a helpful syntax for me.